# How do I combine data from multiple rows into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I’m using SQL Server 2008. I have data as in this table:

```
Team    Email              Groups
------- ------------------ ------
|Team1|-|email0@email.com|-|A|
|Team1|-|email1@email.com|-|B|
|Team1|-|email2@email.com|-|C|
|Team2|-|email3@email.com|-|A|
|Team2|-|email4@email.com|-|B|
|Team2|-|email5@email.com|-|C|
```

I want to get the data in this format:

```
Team    A                  B                  C
------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
|Team1|-|email0@email.com|-|email1@email.com|-|email2@email.com|
|Team2|-|email3@email.com|-|email4@email.com|-|email5@email.com|
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What you're trying to do is Pivot, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx The syntax is sometimes tricky to work out.

Comment: Always 3 groups? Always same number of rows per group?

Comment: @gbn, yes... always three groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using PIVOT You can do the following

```
With SampleData AS 
(
SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email0@email.com' as email, 'A' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email1@email.com' as email, 'B' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email2@email.com' as email, 'C' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email3@email.com' as email, 'A' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email4@email.com' as email, 'B' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email5@email.com' as email, 'C' as Groups
)
SELECT Team, A, B,C FROM 
(SELECT * FROM SampleData) source
PIVOT
(MAX(email) FOR Groups IN ([A], [B], [C]) )as pvt
```

Produces

```
Team  A                B                C
----- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
Team1 email0@email.com email1@email.com email2@email.com
Team2 email3@email.com email4@email.com email5@email.com
```

See a working [Data.SE example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2331/sample-for-8729296)

In a DB that doesn't support PIVOT you can instead do multiple joins to your table. Although you may want to anyway, since as GBN pointed out, since we're not using an aggregate.

```
With SampleData AS 
(
SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email0@email.com' as email, 'A' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email1@email.com' as email, 'B' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team1' as Team , 'email2@email.com' as email, 'C' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email3@email.com' as email, 'A' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email4@email.com' as email, 'B' as Groups
UNION SELECT 'Team2' as Team , 'email5@email.com' as email, 'C' as Groups
)

SELECT 
    source.Team,
    A.email,
    B.email,
    C.email
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT TEAM From SampleData) source
    LEFT JOIN SampleData A 
    ON source.Team = A.Team
     AND A.GROUPS = 'A'
    LEFT JOIN SampleData B 
    ON source.Team = B.Team
    AND B.GROUPS = 'B'
    LEFT JOIN SampleData C 
    ON source.Team = C.Team
    AND C.GROUPS = 'C'
```

See a working [Data.SE example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2332/sample-for-8729296-version-2)

Comment: Personally, I'd probably self join if no aggregation is needed

Comment: @gbn I see your point and updated my answer but I'm not all that excited about `SELECT DISTINCT TEAM From SampleData` either, but that may just be the sample data.

Comment: This works except that I still get nulls for the rows for instance here is a sample row from my results..

`Team1 NULL NULL email1@email.com`
`Team1 email2@email.com NULL NULL`
`Team1 NULL email3@email.com NULL`

I was hoping to get this...

`Team1 email1@email.com email2@email.com email3@email.com`

Comment: @Conrad Frix: may not be needed if "Always same number of rows per group? " as per my comment. But thanks, +1