# Restricting COUNT in a grouped SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Lets say I have the following table structure:

```
+--------------------------------------------+     +------------------------+     +--------------------+
|                   videos                   |     |       borrowings       |     |     customers      |
+-----+------------------------+-------------+     +----------+-------------+     +-----+--------+-----+
| id  | title                  | genre       |     | video_id | customer_id |     | id  | name   | sex |
+-----+------------------------+-------------+     +----------+-------------+     +-----+--------+-----+
| 101 | Transformers III       | Action      |     | 101      | 101         |     | 101 | Alfred | m   |
+-----+------------------------+-------------+     +----------+-------------+     +-----+--------+-----+
| 102 | DNS - The Code of Life | Documentary |     | 102      | 102         |     | 102 | Agathe | f   |
+-----+------------------------+-------------+     +----------+-------------+     +-----+--------+-----+
                                                   video_id    -> videos.id
                                                   customer_id -> customers.id
```

I want to select the number of borrowings from males and females separated and grouped by genre.

```
+-------------+-------+---------+
| Genre       | Males | Females |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| Action      | 1     | 0       |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| Documentary | 0     | 1       |
+-------------+-------+---------+
```

My first try just selects the number of borrowings grouped by genre

```
SELECT
  v.genre "Genre",
  COUNT(c.id) "Count"
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.genre
ORDER BY v.genre ASC;
```

I know that I can do SELECTs inside the COUNT-function (or any other aggregate function), so my idea was to do something similar to this (pseudo code):

```
SELECT
  v.genre "Genre",
  COUNT(SELECT c.id FROM parent_selection_set WHERE c.sex = "m") "Borrowings from males",
  ...
```

but I doubt that there is a concept like `parent_selection_set`. **I'm wondering whether there is a way to do this with SELECTs within the count or if there is an even better way to obtain the desired result?**

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The fastest solution:

This is how you would typically get the result you're looking for

```
SELECT
  v.genre "Genre",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.sex = 'm' THEN 1 END) "Males",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.sex = 'f' THEN 1 END) "Females"
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.genre
ORDER BY v.genre ASC;
```

You'll find plenty of questions here on Stack Overflow, looking for how to create [`PIVOT` tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql%20pivot). This solution is fast, because the two `COUNT(...)` operations can be done in memory after the join.

#### The solution you were looking for:

For completeness' sake, here's the syntax that you were looking for with subqueries:

```
SELECT
  v.genre "Genre",
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers c WHERE b.customer_id = c.id AND c.sex = 'm') "Males",
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers c WHERE b.customer_id = c.id AND c.sex = 'f') "Females",
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
GROUP BY v.genre
ORDER BY v.genre ASC;
```

These are called [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), and they're much slower than any `JOIN`-based solution because usually, the subquery has to be executed for every row of the top-level query.

Comment: So I can use the `CASE` syntax in aggregate functions to go over every entry in the result set? That's great :)

Comment: @Cubinator73: The way it works is that `COUNT(expr)` counts only those rows for which `expr IS NOT NULL`. Since I left out the `CASE .. ELSE` clause, all "`ELSE`" will be `NULL`, and thus not counted.

Comment: Took me 10 minutes to write my answer, and I am posting it 5 minutes too late, again :)

Comment: @ThomasG: It happens to the best

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities which depend on the RDBMS. 
Since you have not gaven the RDBMS, here's a general SQL for this (normally working on all RDBMS but a bit long)

```
SELECT T.gr, T.cnt AS Total, TM.cnt AS Males, TF.cnt AS Females
FROM
(
    SELECT  v.genre AS gr, COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
    FROM videos v
    INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
    INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
    GROUP BY v.genre
) T
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  v.genre AS gr, COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
    FROM videos v
    INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
    INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
    WHERE c.sex = 'm'
    GROUP BY v.genre
) TM ON T.gr=TM.gr
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  v.genre AS gr, COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
    FROM videos v
    INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
    INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
    WHERE c.sex = 'f'
    GROUP BY v.genre
) TF ON T.gr=TF.gr
ORDER BY T.gr ASC
```

In MySQL or Oracle you can do something like this :

```
SELECT
  v.genre "Genre",
  COUNT(c.id) AS Tot,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.sex='m') THEN c.id ELSE 0 END) AS Males,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.sex='f') THEN c.id ELSE 0 END) AS Females
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN borrowings b ON v.id = b.video_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON b.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY v.genre
ORDER BY v.genre ASC;
```

In Access or SQL Server you can use the PIVOT statements

Comment: Oracle has pivot. In fact it's better than SQL server because you pivot more than one field (e.g. pivoting sex and age). Also in MySQL you can do [`SUM(c.sex='m')`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf738c/3) and avoid the case

Comment: well, yes you are right on everything. on the other hand I never stated that Oracle didn't have pivot, and I said _something like this_, and _Oracle **OR** MySQL_. The goal was not too list the best SQL statement for every RDBMS around but to give a general overview on the approach.My queries are corrects, aren't they?

Comment: The SQL is fine. I'd say the the other sentences are misleading. In the case of Access the statement is technically incorrect. Access uses `Transform`. If you want to avoid annoying comments like mine you might want to [name the syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8729478/119477) and not the db or be more clear about which DB's support what

Comment: If you want to play this game, you are technically incorrect as well because Access uses `Transform...PIVOT`, but I won't play this game any longer because this is going nowhere.

Comment: Very nicely done. I'd forgotten about the PIVOT on the end.

Comment: txs and no worries. The fact is: **the whole question is misleading**, because he didnt provided the RDBMS. I could have listed all best statements for doing this on RDBMS I am working on mostly everyday: SQL Server, Access, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, Sybase. But I didn't want to do that because the first statement works on all of them. I gave the second one as an example of how to do it another way on a specific RDBMS. Hope you got it

Comment: Your `COUNT(CASE...)` solution is wrong. It will count all the rows.

Comment: @ThomasG Not providing the [RDMS isn't a new complaint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107783/148672) You could use the [pro forma comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136610/148672) but people often answer before the OP tags it.